# PreloadEnabled not available to be set as Website Defaults on IIS

Tags: web, iis

I am looking to set PreloadEnabled to True for to be default for sites on an IIS Server, but the option does not show up in the Website Defaults dialog? is there something i am missing here? I can set it for individual sites that are already created but not the default configurations?

[image: Website Defaults]

I have tried setting it in the Configuration Editor dialog as well as the Website Defaults dialog shown above, but both do not contain that setting.

**Edit**:
wanted to add more information such as the following screenshot of the Configuration Editor.

[image: IIS Configuration Editor]

I understand that the property `PreloadEnabled` is available in the `(Collection)`tab to be set for indivdual sites, but i wanted to ask if this option is also available to set as the default for newly created sites?

Comment: I can set `PreloadEnabled` in the default website in my iis10. First, please check whether you have installed the `Application Initialization` feature. You can also try adding this `PreloadEnabled` to the applicationhost.config file: `<application path="/" preloadEnabled= "true">`.

Comment: @samwu Yes, `Application Initialization` is installed, i also did check `PreloadEnabled` is enabled on the `application path="/"`in the applicationhost.config file, but when i created a test site, the newly created site still has the preloadEnabled value as false. so i wonder if it is even possible to set the defaults for this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preloadEnabled` is only introduced in IIS 8.0, so if you cannot see it even with Configuration Editor, you are likely using IIS 7.x which unfortunately is too old,

https://github.com/lextm/iis_schema/blame/fe51c91e0fe1fd742bb7d50e0742cb9d027f25e4/IIS_schema.xml#L586

> BTW, even IIS 8.x reached end of life, so you can only use IIS 10 if you want to get support.

If you are indeed with IIS 10, make sure you configure this setting under `applicationDefaults`, as that's the right place, not `siteDefaults`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Lex, I should have confirmed the version of IIS i am on (IIS 10), but i still do no see the setting `preloadEnabled` under `applicationDefaults` or even anywhere in the default site configurations.

Comment: It is not true to say "even anywhere in ...". Like the schema indicates, this `preloadEnabled` attribute is defined on `applicationDefaults` element under a `site` element. So, in Configuration Editor, you need to open the section of `system.applicationHost/sites`, open a site from `(Collection)`, and then in the Collection Editor dialog to find the right `applicationDefaults` instance under each sites. Not sure why it was designed that way and that design makes it less useful.

Comment: I added an addtional edit to my post, i understand that you can set this for indivudal sites, but i wanted to ask if it is possible to be set as the default for newly created sites or is this not advised?

Comment: @Andy as the actual configuration schema presents, it is impossible to be set as the default for all new sites. That's why I said in this way it is "less useful".